# Online game using .net technologies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, compare, lamp, online-game

I am new in game development, but I'm thinking about creating online browser game on asp.net mvc3 using entity framework for ORM data mapping and SQL Server 2008 DB for data data storage.
I would like to hear your thoughts about this.
What advantages and disadvantages of this approach. Why is it worse than using classic LAMP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first of all costs. As I assume you are paying for the licences, second is speed(linux is faster than windows), third portability and safety (apache is more secure than IIS and also faster) and apache/mysql/php can run on windows while IIS and will not work on something else.
Overall more Lamp hosters than Windows hosters as far as I know.
Then PHP is faster than ASP (execution speed and development speed), cheaper to develop, much more flexible and lighter(even if you use a framework like symphony or Zend).
examples: Facebook works with php, Yahoo works with PHP, IBM is befriending PHP . MySQL is fast and easy to maintain.
Microsoft Technology is for corporations (As my personal opinion on their technology, I rather keep it to my self, raise your hands IE6 friends). If you are going for PHP or MySql though their flexibility can be tricky, as you can do a lot of things, if you do not master your school theory you might end up with a monster.

Comment: Linux/Windows doesn't matter. It's IIS vs. Apache, although not really as ASP.Net can run on Linux. PHP being faster than ASP.Net, I'd love to see proof on that. Finally, IE6 is 10 years old, FF wasn't even out yet.

Comment: @Rangoric if you take two pros one on PHP one on ASP.Net you will see the speed difference(there is a small difference but there is one in favor of PHP), in the end the big difference is made by skill. While the problem with IE6 is that it does not respect the standards, that is it's main problem, the standards were there 10 years ago.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Actually here is another question then. Now I have experience of asp.net development and IIS configuration. I have never worked with Apache and php. Here is the question if it will be better to learn LAMP or make startup with .NET?

Comment: Best way is the shortest way and the shortest way is the one you know best. Now, if you are in the .NET business for 1 year (+half at most), you can take a shot at PHP, as long as you program by standards like you were thought in school, working on PHP does not mean you are going to forget .NET, but if you have like 2+ years of .NET experience than stick to it. In the end a good concept works well on any platform.

Comment: @Catalin what proof of this do you have? Because all I keep seeing is you professing things, then not actually supplying any proof besides "it seems like it". So please show PHP faster in execution speed than .Net, surely there is a benchmark of some sort. Especially since PHP has a .Net compiler. I mean really. I want to see some of this proof.

Comment: I can not give you any actual proof obviously, it would mean that I must develop tow similar large enough systems in the two technologies, taking the best out of them and run a benchmark, a fact that is actually impossible. What I want to state that the difference is made by programmers and architects not by languages at this level of detail, I can show you Java applications that run very very fast. I am not saying that .NET is better or PHP (Java is the best :) ), the guy asked for an opinion from our experience, I gave him mine.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I think I'll try to do that with .NET. You helped me to make this decision. :)

Comment: This is a bad answer based on nothing more than assumptions. -1